# Telegram bots not working for all users

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, botlibre

I have created several Telegram bots. They work for my account and also on several other accounts that I have tested with.

But I get reports from several users saying the bots never respond.

It there some user setting that would prevent an account from getting messages from bots? Or any other idea why it would not work for some accounts?

Comment: edit your question and post part of your code that respond user requests

Comment: you must see your response log after bot send message. you get "bot was blocked by user" if user blocks your bot.

Comment: the bot never gets the user's messages, the webhook is never called for some users

Comment: i am also facing the same issue. i can see webhook logs for my chats but not for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found the issue, it was pebcak.

This issue was it was failing for users that had no last name set in their account because our code was accessing the last_name from the json data.

So make sure your code does not rely on a first or last name.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a pebcak.. Considering the code failed to consider the possibility that users may not have set the last_name.

Answer (score 0):

> But I get reports from several users saying the bots never respond.

This is very unusable information. In default all users are equal for the bot usage and no difference between any users if you don't implement it programmatically. But if they says so then try send the **POST** query to those users in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for example and take a look in response. After this it must be clear what kind of problem there.

**An example of POST**:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{your_bot_token}/sendMessage?chat_id={user_chat_id}&text=test
```

*Note that chat_id those users required.*

Comment: hoping that someone else has had the same issue

Comment: I get "{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat not found"}"

Comment: I never see the webhook called on my server for these users

Comment: @James so what do you think about it? It seems like wrong chat_id

Comment: @James can you tell me about your develop stuff?

Comment: if you get "chat not found", maybe your user delete his/her account and again register in telegram with same phone but his/her chat_id is changed.