# Telegram bot - only works for me but not for other users

Tags: telegram-bot

So I created this telegram bot. Every hour I get a message with a random quote.
It is working perfectly fine for me.

Now I wanted a friend of mine to see the bot in action. So I told him to add the bot as well to his telegram and send to the bot: `"\start"`.

However, he is not receiving any of the bot messages (I still receive them). Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Start Command is `/start` and not `\start`

Comment: Also make sure, your friend had not stopped bot. If so, ask him to Restart bot.

Comment: I was actually using the right start command. My friend has no power over the bot. Just added the bot as a contact. Maybe there’s a step missing …

Comment: My friend has no power over the bot. - he can stop/ban your bot. If that is the case, he will not receive any message from your bot.

Comment: Okay. I just created a new telegram account to try it out. So on my original account I receive the messages normally. On my secondary account I don’t.

Comment: Can you show how are you sending message?

Comment: Please share your code. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

[Did you check this one out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108349/telegram-bots-not-working-for-all-users)

Try checking your code and the data it's reaching out. It can be something very similar to this one.

Comment: Please see [answer]. This is more of a comment!

Comment: I did check not my issue.